# Zone Index Disabled for Web-Parts In Share Point 2013 Designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part

I am not able to change the zone index of web part in SP2013 Designer.How can i do this ?

[image]

Comment: Can you share screen shot?

Comment: Are you in Advanced Edit Mode?

Comment: Hey Amal  I try this  Edit page  then select the webpart then Edit WebPart  after that select the Layout property  in layout property Zone index is disabled.

Comment: Are you working on a web part page or a wiki page? Zone index is disabled on Wiki pages because there are no zones really. Zones are on webpart Pages. Check to see if your page is in a Wiki Page Library.

Comment: Hey Ova its Web part page.